# Which British WW1 regiment is shown in this photograph?

Tags: identification, world-war-one

[image: a photo of my grandfather in uniform]This is a photograph of my Grandfather John Wilson who was born in Randlestown, Northern Ireland in February 1885. He moved to Scotland and served in WW1. He survived the war and died on 31st December 1966 in Partick Glasgow. Can anyone assist me in identifying his regiment from this photograph?

Comment: Without better resolution on the cap badge and the shoulder epaulets, I can't offer much hope. WW1 uniforms were, as you undoubtedly noticed, rather *uniform*.

Comment: The cap badge looks fairly distinctive (wreath with something oval in the middle?) - I haven't been able to find any likely matches though

Comment: Purely judging by the information and the cut of the uniform... I wonder if this is a Cameronian (Scottish Rifle) soldier. The hat badge could also work. However, the hat shape is odd. I'm basing my guess on this photo: https://www.wartimememoriesproject.com/greatwar/images/BREED,%20F%20-%20Fred%20Breed%20with%20wife%20Mavis,%20WWI_1.jpg of L/Cpl. Fred Breed, 1st Battalion Scottish Rifles (photo from 23th Oct 1918)